# Is it possible to dynamically resize an image with PHP when the image is not on the local server?

Tags: php

The image doesn't have to be saved, but is it still possible to resize it? Would I have to cache it?

It can be done with CSS. This blog explains how: http://blog.sachinkraj.com/how-to-resize-images-with-css/

Comment: Depends on how you want to resize it. If you want to display an image from a remote site, you can resize it via CSS. If you want to actually resize the image you will have to download a copy of the image locally then resize the local version.

Comment: CSS will degrade the quality so I dont want to do that

Comment: Quality degradation will only occur if you opt to increase the size of an image. Otherwise if you maintain aspect ratios, won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have to be loaded into memory at very minimum, but there's no reason you couldn't load it into memory from a remote location (file_get_contents or cURL or whatever), manipulate it and spit it back out to the client.

As far as performance goes, unless the image can be accessed over a very high speed connection (LAN level fast), it's probably going to cause a very significant lag in processing the image.  To alleviate this hit, you could cache it, but no, you would not have to.  (And if you were going to cache it, it would likely be better to cache the processed version.)

Comment: He probably didn't understand you were talking about image manipulation using something like gd. The question isn't very clear. Have an upvote.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought on it...  Or one of the people who assumed it was on a remote *web*server and thus there was no need to download it all (for the server anyway).  Eh, who knows.  Down and runs annoy the hell out of me though.